# How do I fix drywall damaged by peeling paint tearing off the outer paper?

Tags: bathroom, drywall, painting

I wanted to paint over my bathroom. The paint was peeling and coming off in large plastic-like strips. I assumed that I could not paint over it, so I ripped off all the peeling paint. It seems some drywall came with because afterwards half the wall was brown paper. I tried putting primer over it but that made it worse and now the wall is really uneven. What do I do?

Comment: You can re coat the wall with a topping compound and a wide mud knife. That or get a texture roller with a pattern you like.

Comment: If you want to smooth out the wall, skim-coat with compound to provide a good surface. Some good advice here: http://diy.stackexchange.com/a/7842/1326. Alternatively, texture the wall to mask the unevenness (probably easier especially if you haven't done much mudding before). Your call depending on which look you like.

Comment: Also, try not to sand the drywall paper, that will make little fuzzies.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to patch the areas, where the paper tore off, and then skim coat the entire wall, so that the patched areas, don't stand out "shinier and flatter", than the rest of the wall.

At this point, Google is your friend, especially if you plan to fix it yourself. You may also be able to get a contractor, to do the whole thing, for a fairly cheap price. Prepping a bathroom for paint, is beer money for some guys.

Research, research, research!